# How many gold particles of radius 144 picometers can fit inside a sphere of radius 5 nanometers.

Tags: geometry

If someone could tell me, and give me a small explanation why, that would be great.
I've tried (Surface Area Of Sphere/Surface Area of Atom)+(Volume of Sphere/ Volume of Atom)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a description of what you've tried and where you're stuck.  This will help people give useful answers at an appropriate level.  (In particular, if you are looking for an *exact* answer, you are actually posing an awfully difficult problem!)

Comment: Gold is pretty soft. Would it be acceptable to squeeze the particles a bit out of shape? In that case, about $(5000/144)^3\approx 41,800$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal packing fraction for identical spheres is $\pi/(3\sqrt{2})$ so it should be close to:

$$n = \frac{\pi V_{b}}{3 \sqrt{2} V_{s}} = \frac{\pi^2 r_b^3}{3\sqrt{2}r_s^3} \approx \frac{(0.74078)(5000)^3}{(144)^3} \approx 31,000.$$